# .htaccess - Rewrite Flash Links?

Tags: flash, .htaccess, redirect

An old client of mine changed domains, and has a Flash only navigation (I know, I know).  However I don't have access to the .fla version of the navigation, so I'm wondering if there's a way to redirect Flash links through .htaccess?

I've tried the normal:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and about every other combination I can think of, but none seem to work.

**Redoing the Flash navigation for standard navigation is not really an option.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you redirecting from the old domain?

Comment: Yes, I need to redirect from the old domain to the new domain.  The problem seems to be that the links are hardcoded into the Flash, and I can't find a way to 'intercept' those links and change them to the new domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.newdomain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Didn't work.  The URL's are correctly re-written on all of the normal links, it's just the Flash links that seem to be the problem.

Comment: How are they different from the others

Comment: I meant how are they put together and called.

Comment: I ended up just redoing the menu.  Would still love to know if there's an answer to this.